# How to convert long decimal to IP Add IPAddress C# work

Tags: c#

I have a short code C# about how to convert long decimal to IP Address. 
But I am not sure about the base logic behind it.
Could someone please explain the idea behind the following code:

```
IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(16885952);
Byte[] b = new Byte[4];
b = ip.GetAddressBytes();
Console.WriteLine("Address: "+b[0]+"." + b[1] + "." + b[2] + "." + b[3]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By hand, using `int` calculation.

```
16885952 % 256 = 192
16885952 / 256 % 256 = 168
16885952 / 256 / 256 % 256 = 1
16885952 / 256 / 256 / 256 = 1
```

Comment: I just need to know how to calculate it by hand when I don't have a computer.

Comment: @Sae I have updated the answer. Please remember to accept it if it answers your question.